# A jquery select options element bug in firefox on mac

Tags: jquery, firefox

i have this select element that on change it sends an ajax call and do some stuff,
 the select element works fine on firefox , google chrome, and IE (windows), but wouldn't work in firefox on mac, nothing happens and i do not know why.
    If anyone can guide me through this or it's a common bug thank you in advance.
    on document ready that what i do

```
$("#r_one").next().attr({
        'for': "r_one",
    'className' : "myClass" 
    });
   var r_one = $("label[for='r_one']").contents();
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
      r_one[r_one.length-1].nodeValue = "myLabel";
    });
```

and there are other code lines such as validating the form by ajax and shwo & hide

Comment: i edited my question, the first part of the code is for adding the for attribute to my radio button, and the second to rename it